# Access log config for homer-7

Tags: access-log

Im starting to in study a project about homer-7, the open source check out from github

After starting the homer-app web successfully.

The default config file of homer is webapp_config.json, http config with port 9080.
I try to create a new conf file and store it at /etc/httpd/conf.d/homer7.conf also listen with the port 9080.

I tried with another the port like 9081 for my new file but it cannot found the bunde of UI.

structure of webapp_config.json:

```
{
    "http_settings": {
        "help": "Settings for the HOMER Webapp Server. If you have gzip_static = false, please be sure that your dist directory has uncompressed .js files",
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": 9080,
        "root": "/usr/local/homer/dist",
        "gzip": true,
        "path": "/",
        "gzip_static": true,
        "debug": false
    },

"system_settings": {
        "help": "Settings for HOMER logs",
        "logpath": "/usr/local/homer/log",
        "logname": "homer-app.log",
        "_loglevels": "can be: fatal, error, warn, info, debug, trace",
        "loglevel": "error",
        "logstdout": false
    }
}
```

My config file /etc/httpd/conf.d/homer7.conf

```
Listen 8080
Define virtual host for HOMER7 on standard http tcp port 80
<VirtualHost *:9080>
ServerAdmin support@yourhost.org
ServerName  homer7.yourhost.org
Directory Root.
DocumentRoot /usr/local/homer
Logfiles
ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/homer-app-error.log
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" parameters: \"%{parameters}n\" username: %{username}n" custom
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/homer-app-access.log custom
</VirtualHost>
```

It working and I can see the log in /var/log/httpd/homer-app-access.log

But it is conflict the port with the http_setting, I can't access to the web UI anymore.

Is there any way to define a new session on the webapp_config.json to get the homer-app-access.log ?

My purpose is catch the access log and store it at  /var/log/httpd/homer-app-access.log.

Thank you